# Proper way to write string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the proper way to concatenate strings in JavaScript? For example, I have this:

```
var addmore ='<tr>'+'<td style="text-align: center">'+currentIndex+'</td>'+'<td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_'+currentIndex+'" value="">'+'</td><td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text"  id="label_'+currentIndex'"></td></tr>'
```

It shows an error in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgxKW/) but I can't find it. I have checked the quotation marks and they seem correct.

Will too many quotation marks cause confusion and errors in JavaScript? Or must `"` be outside of `'`?

Comment: Syntax highlighting is useful sometimes. Scroll across and look at where things differ.

Comment: `id="label_'+currentIndex'"` missing the `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better and neater way to do it:

```
 var addmore ='<tr>'+
             '<td style="text-align: center">'+currentIndex+'</td>'+                        
             '<td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_'+currentIndex+'" value=""></td>'+
             '<td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text"  id="label_'+currentIndex+'"></td>'+
             '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

For string concatination I tend to use string format like in python. Define string format at the top of the code in common.js file which is used by all pages in project

try this (http://jsfiddle.net/9Xw8Q/1/)

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
                ? args[number]
                : match
                ;
        });
    };
}
```

and then use it like this

```
currentIndex = 20  

 var addmore ='<tr><td style="text-align: center">{0}</td><td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_{0}" value=""></td><td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text"  id="label_{0}"></td></tr>'.format(currentIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the knowledge! This can be of my future reference. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can see the output here: http://jsbin.com/abiduw/1/edit

```
currentIndex=5;
var addMore = '<tr><td style="text-align: center">'+currentIndex+'</td><td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_'+currentIndex+'" value=""></td><td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="label_'+currentIndex+'"></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing jsbin!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Proper like this

```
var addmore ='<tr><td style="text-align: center">'+currentIndex+'</td><td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_'+currentIndex+'" value=""></td><td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text"  id="label_'+currentIndex+'"></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Why to downvote..??any reason

Comment: it wasnt me who vote u down. let me vote u up! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var addmore = '<tr><td style="text-align: center">' + currentIndex + '</td><td id="small"><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="number_' 
              + currentIndex + '" value="">' + '</td><td><input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text"  id="label_' + currentIndex + '"></td></tr>';
```